# Why "if condition" in two list comprehantions work faster then one cycle for with 2 two conditions?

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

```
import time
from random import random
from typing import List


def test(arr: List[int] | None = None) -> None:
    if not arr:
        raise TypeError("Variable arr must exist!")
    
    opp = arr.pop()

    def check_time(func, msg):
        t0 = time.perf_counter()
        func()
        print(f"{msg}\ntime - {time.perf_counter() - t0}")

    def first_method():
        more_arr = [e for e in arr if e > opp]
        less_arr = [e for e in arr if e < opp]
        return less_arr, more_arr

    def second_method():
        more_arr, less_arr = [], []
        for e in arr:
            if e > opp:
                more_arr.append(e)
            elif e < opp:
                less_arr.append(e)
        return less_arr, more_arr

    check_time(first_method, "first_method")
    check_time(second_method, "second_method")
    """
    [RESULT]
    first_method
    time - 0.1035286999976961
    second_method
    time - 0.12783881399809616
    """


def main() -> None:
    test([int(random() * 1000) for _ in range(1_000_000)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

RESULT:

first_method: time - 0.10790603799978271

second_method: time - 0.1264369229975273

-------------------------------------------------------------

I wont to know why first_*method() faster then second*_method()?

How work "if" condition in list_comprehension from the point of view of optimization?

Comment: Could you please edit? "comprehantions" -> "comprehensions"; "then" -> "than" (title and body); "2 two" -> "two"; "wont" -> "want"

Comment: @LoverofStructure There's a feature for edits / edit suggestions. You should use it.

Comment: @KlausD. I tried, and the edit queue is full (and I waited in line for a *long* time last time I did try to wait), plus we need to draw the OP's attention to the (relative) importance of spelling. It's easy for you to check my record, which ought to prevent you from concluding that I don't know about the "feature for edits / edit suggestions" or that one "should" use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this third method to see that the retrieving of the `append` methods needs a lot of time:

```
    def third_method():
        more_arr, less_arr = [], []
        m = more_arr.append
        l = less_arr.append
        
        for e in arr:
            if e > opp:
                m(e)
            elif e < opp:
                l(e)
        return less_arr, more_arr
```

This method is usually even slightly faster than the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cProfile module to see information about functions or how long they take internally

Run once

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import cProfile
    cProfile.run('main()')
```

```
first_method
time - 0.06351780006662011
second_method
time - 0.1859593999106437
         1999012 function calls in 0.493 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.493    0.493 <string>:1(<module>)
        2    0.005    0.003    0.250    0.125 test.py:13(check_time)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.061    0.061 test.py:18(first_method)
        1    0.036    0.036    0.036    0.036 test.py:19(<listcomp>)
        1    0.025    0.025    0.025    0.025 test.py:20(<listcomp>)
        1    0.120    0.120    0.183    0.183 test.py:23(second_method)
        1    0.006    0.006    0.493    0.493 test.py:44(main)
        1    0.178    0.178    0.237    0.237 test.py:45(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.250    0.250 test.py:7(test)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.493    0.493 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time.perf_counter}
   998993    0.064    0.000    0.064    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
  1000000    0.059    0.000    0.059    0.000 {method 'random' of '_random.Random' objects}
```

```
ncalls
for the number of calls.

tottime
for the total time spent in the given function (and excluding time made in calls to sub-functions)

percall
is the quotient of tottime divided by ncalls

cumtime
is the cumulative time spent in this and all subfunctions (from invocation till exit). This figure is accurate even for recursive functions.

percall
is the quotient of cumtime divided by primitive calls

filename:lineno(function)
provides the respective data of each function
```

998993    0.064    0.000    0.064    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}

append takes more time than list comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

Performance will vary depending on your hardware platform and Python version.

I have modified the original code to use *randint()* rather than the unnecessary calculation using *random()*. That has no effect on the timing.

On my machine *first_method()* is slower than *second_method()*.

It's worth noting that in *first_method()* the *arr* list is enumerated twice (once per comprehension) whereas in *second_method()* it's only enumerated once

```
from random import randint
from time import perf_counter

def test(arr: list) -> None:
    opp = arr.pop()

    def check_time(func, msg):
        t0 = perf_counter()
        func()
        print(f"{msg} duration = {perf_counter() - t0:.4f}s")  

    def first_method():
        more_arr = [e for e in arr if e > opp]
        less_arr = [e for e in arr if e < opp]
        return less_arr, more_arr

    def second_method():
        more_arr, less_arr = [], []
        for e in arr:
            if e > opp:
                more_arr.append(e)
            elif e < opp:
                less_arr.append(e)
        return less_arr, more_arr

    check_time(first_method, 'First')
    check_time(second_method, 'Second')


def main() -> None:
    test([randint(0, 1_000) for _ in range(1_000_000)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
First duration = 0.0472s
Second duration = 0.0367s
```

**Platform:**

```
Python 3.11.2
macOS 13.2.1
CPU 3GHz 10-Core Intel Xeon W
RAM 32GB
```